# Is it possible to set rows to be invisible by default when adding to DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As per title, is it possible to set DataGridView rows to `visible = false` by default when adding rows?

```
//I am adding rows using the following method..
...
dgvNOPDocs.Rows.Add("Stuff", "MoreStuff");
...
```

Is there a DataGridView setting or cell style that enables us do this?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh because there are too many rows being added and when I run a filter to make certain ones invisible, it takes too long. If they are loaded invisible, the filter works much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this way You can choose would be `row` visible or not while adding to `DataGridView` :

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow(); //create new row
row.CreateCells(dgvNOPDocs);   //create cells based on dgv columns
row.SetValues({"Stuff", "MoreStuff"});  //set values (assuming there is only two columns in Your dgv
if (some condition why row would be invisible) { row.Visible = false; }
dgvNOPDocs.Rows.Add(row);  //adding new row into dgv
```

I hope so this will help You (and I hope so, too, I make correct convert from vb.net to c#).

Answer (score 1):

try handle `RowsAdded` event of grid and hide new rows there

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // attach handler
    dgvNOPDocs.RowsAdded += GridOnRowsAdded;

    // test
    dgvNOPDocs.Rows.Add("Stuff");
    dgvNOPDocs.RowCount = 3;
}

private void GridOnRowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    // hide rows
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < e.RowIndex + e.RowCount; i++)
    {                
        if (dgvNOPDocs.Rows[i].IsNewRow == false)
            dgvNOPDocs.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```